# Is there a R function to add points in a dendrogram?

Tags: r, tree, dendrogram

I want to create a dendrogram in R and to add some points to get something similar to what is shown in the image below [tree with points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVQ8m.png). I have no idea of how to put the points in a certain branch and at a certain height.

I have to create this algorithm [algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tihb.png) and to add the points when a mutation event happens. I have to find a way to specify the coordinates of the points to write them inside the loop that I have to make. I have done another algorithm where there are just coalescent events but it is very similar to this one without the mutation events. I add this algorithm here:

```
##Algorithm 1

n=10

# Compute distances and hierarchical clustering
dd <- dist(scale(seq(1:n)), method = "euclidean")
hc <- hclust(dd, method = "ward.D2")
hc$labels=c(1:n)
hc$order=c(1:n)

x=c(-n:-1)
i=1
T_k=0

while(length(x)>1){
  lambda=choose(length(x),2)
  T_k=rexp(1,rate=lambda)+T_k
  hc$height[i]=T_k
  c=sample(x,2,replace=F)
  x=setdiff(x,c)
  x=append(x,i,after=0)
  hc$merge[i,1]=c[1]
  hc$merge[i,2]=c[2]
  i=i+1

}


hcd <- as.dendrogram(hc)
# Default plot
plot(hcd, type = "rectangle", ylab = "Height",main="Gene tree")
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Would you be able to produce a minimal example of what you tried so far? https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex

Comment: After you plot the dendrogram, `par("usr")` will get you the coordinates of the corners of the plot. Integer values on the x-axis will represent the position of the leaves of the dendrogram. The y-axis gives the height. For the branches you will have to estimate their x-axis position or use the `locator()` function.

Comment: I have just edited the post and I explain a bit better what I need